# How can I display fewer labels on the X-axis when it is an instance of CategoryAxis? (JFreeChart library)

Tags: jfreechart

I have a CategoryAxis used with a BarChart where I have too many labels to be readable.
I would like to set a visible interval for the labels, so let's say each ten values the label is printed.
I read some posts where setTickUnit() method is recommended, but such method doesn't exist in CategoryAxis.

Here you can see a sample of what I am referring to, as you see I have tens of dates so you can't read them:

[image]

Any pointer or recommendation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a pretty good explanation of the problem (and some solutions) in the [FAQ](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17397#p80593) section of the JFreeChart homepage.
You might be better of with an `XYPlot` and an `XYBarRenderer`.